# Why is the datatable not displayed in my shinyapp?

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, dt

I have a problem, that a datatable is not always shown in my app. Let me show you an example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  "Bli",
  checkboxInput("ch","display datatable",value = TRUE),
  shinyjs::hidden(DT::DTOutput("dt")),
  "Blob",
  #DT::DTOutput("dt2"),
  "Blub"
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$ch,{
    if(input$ch){
      shinyjs::show("dt")
    } else {
      shinyjs::hide("dt")
    }
  })
  output$dt <- DT::renderDT(DT::datatable(iris))
  output$dt2 <- DT::renderDT(DT::datatable(iris))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If I uncomment the dt2-output, it works as expected: The table is rendered and shown when the checkbox is checked. However, as is the table is not shown at all. Why is that? I cannot find any logical connection between `dt` and `dt2`.

What can I change so that I do not have to have a second datatable in order for the first one to work properly?

Comment: Ronak Shan solution work - I think you should avoid `shinyjs::hidden` in the ui and use the `shinyjs::show/hide` in the server to show/hide initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as expected if you don't keep the `dt` table `hidden` by default.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  "Bli",
  checkboxInput("ch","display datatable",value = TRUE),
  DT::DTOutput("dt"),
  "Blob",
  #DT::DTOutput("dt2"),
  "Blub"
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$ch,{
    if(input$ch){
      shinyjs::show("dt")
    } else {
      shinyjs::hide("dt")
    }
  })
  output$dt <- DT::renderDT(DT::datatable(iris))
  output$dt2 <- DT::renderDT(DT::datatable(iris))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Set the `checkboxInput` value to `FALSE` then the datatable will hide by default